# Not getting the desired data as a object in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to get the **users' data** according to their **profile**.
If user1 and user2 belong to a similar profile, I should get users'

- User ID
- User Name
- Permission Sets
- Queue Members
- User Package

I had made a class **UserData** such that I can get an **object** as return value.

```apex
@TestVisible public class UserData {
    public Id userId;
    public String userName;
    public String permissionsSets = 'NA';
    public String queueMembers = 'NA';
    public String userPackage = 'NA';

    public UserData(String name, Id id) {
        this.userName = name;
        this.userId = id;
    }
}
```

Here is the **Apex class** I am using to get the users record

```apex
    public with sharing class profileListController {

    // return the profiles
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<Profile> getProfiles() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile];
    }

    /**
    * @description 
    * @author ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc | 02-21-2022 
    * @param profile 
    * @return List<userData> 
    **/
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<UserData> getUsers(Id profile){
        List<User> userDataList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Profile.Id = :profile ];
        List<UserData> allData = new List<UserData>();

        for (User user: userDataList) {
            UserData newUser = new UserData(user.Name, user.Id);

            String permissionSet = getPermissionSet(user.Id);
            if (permissionSet.length() != 0)
                newUser.permissionsSets = permissionSet;

            String packages = getUserPackage(user.Id);
            if (packages.length() != 0)
                newUser.userPackage = packages;
            
            String queueMember = getGroupMemeber(user.Id);
            if (queueMember.length() != 0)
                newUser.queueMembers = queueMember;
            
            allData.add(newUser);
        }

        return allData;
    }

    /**
    * @description 
    * @author ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc | 02-21-2022 
    * @param user 
    * @return String 
    **/
    //@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static String getPermissionSet(Id user){
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> temp = [SELECT Id, PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = :user];
        String str = '';

        for (PermissionSetAssignment p: temp) 
            str += p.PermissionSet.Name + ', ';
        
        return str;
    }

    /**
    * @description 
    * @author ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc | 02-21-2022 
    * @param user 
    * @return String 
    **/
    //@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static String getUserPackage(Id user){
        List<UserPackageLicense> temp = [SELECT Id, PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix FROM UserPackageLicense WHERE UserId = :user];
        String str = '';

        for (UserPackageLicense p: temp) 
            str += p.PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix + ', ';
        
        return str;
    }

    /**
    * @description 
    * @author ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc | 02-21-2022 
    * @param user 
    * @return String 
    **/
    //@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static String getGroupMemeber(Id user){
        List<GroupMember> temp = [SELECT Group.DeveloperName FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId = :user];
        String str = '';

        for (GroupMember p: temp) 
            str += p.Group.DeveloperName + ', ';
        
        return str;
    }

    @TestVisible public class UserData {
        public Id userId;
        public String userName;
        public String permissionsSets = 'NA';
        public String queueMembers = 'NA';
        public String userPackage = 'NA';

        public UserData(String name, Id id) {
            this.userName = name;
            this.userId = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Also the **Javascript** function I am using whenever a user changes the profile from the picklist

```javascript
handleChange(event) {

    this.inputProfile = event.detail.value;
    //console.log(event.detail.value);
    //console.log(this.inputProfile)
    
    getUsers({ profile: this.inputProfile })
        .then(result => {
            this.usersDataList = result;
            console.log(this.usersDataList)
            console.log(this.usersDataList.userId)
            console.log(this.usersDataList.userName)
            this.error = undefined;
            //this.setValues();
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.usersDataList[0].userName), this.usersDataList[0].permissionsSets)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.usersList = undefined;
            console.log(error)
        });
    //console.log(this.usersList[0].Name)
}
```

So the problem is: Whenever I try to get the data of users, it says **undefined**.

[image]

Can someone please help me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns a **list** of items.

So to get some information of about your user, you need to take it out from the list first:

1. `console.log(this.usersDataList[0].userId)`
   OR
2. iterate through your array and do sth with it:

   `this.usersDataList.forEach(user => console.log(user.userId));`

Comment: Actually I have done that too, still shows undefined

Comment: @SahilKumar could you send a piece of code that you've changed and attach a screenshot with the content of console logs + expanded console log from this:
            console.log(this.usersDataList)(line 157)